# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in MLPRegressor

Tags: python, neural-network

When trying to run this I get the error below. I'm not really sure how to solve this. Since I'm pretty new to this so I'd really appreciate any help.

here I am using different models for check which one is best here..

check this import code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random
import math
import time
import operator 
import folium
import plotly.offline as py

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, BayesianRidge
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from fbprophet import Prophet
from fbprophet.plot import plot_plotly, add_changepoints_to_plot
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import statsmodels.api as sm
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
%matplotlib inline
```

Model devlopment for polynomial regression

```
data1 = confirmed_df.melt(value_vars=dates1, var_name='Date', value_name='Confirmed')
data1 = data1.groupby('Date')['Confirmed'].sum().reset_index()
data1.head()

X = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=data1.Date)
y = data1.Confirmed
y -= y.mean()

#cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1,random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1,
                                                    random_state=0)
```

Model run:

```
print("Training MLPRegressor...")
tic = time()
est = make_pipeline(QuantileTransformer(),
                    MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(32, 35, 10),
                                 learning_rate_init=0.01,
                                 max_iter=50000, alpha=0.0005,
                                 early_stopping=True))
est.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("done in {:.3f}s".format(time() - tic))
print("Test R2 score: {:.2f}".format(est.score(X_test, y_test)))

# model = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=[32, 32, 10],activation='relu', solver='adam', max_iter=50000, alpha=0.0005, random_state=26)
# _=model.fit(x, y)
```

**Getting error of:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-496d8c3b8b48> in <module>
      1 print("Training MLPRegressor...")
----> 2 tic = time()
      3 est = make_pipeline(QuantileTransformer(),
      4                     MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(32, 35, 10),
      5                                  learning_rate_init=0.01,

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Could you please also provide the code for the imports?

Comment: @BjörnB Please check the code update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to track the performance of your script with the `tic=time()`
 however you need to specify the module  from which you want to call the method time() so to solve this just call `tic = time.time()` see [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_date_time.htm) provdied below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time;  # This is required to include time module.

ticks = time.time()
print "Number of ticks since 12:00am, January 1, 1970:", ticks
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `time` is a module, not a function.  Do you have a line like this at the top of your script?

`import time`

If so, then to get the current time you want to call the `time` function within the `time` module:

```
tic = time.time()
```

If you use `mypy` you can catch errors like this before running your code.  Running `mypy` on code that calls the `time` module as if it were a function produces `error: Module not callable`.  Using the `reveal_type` macro shows the difference:

```
import time

reveal_type(time)       # note: Revealed type is '_importlib_modulespec.ModuleType'
reveal_type(time.time)  # note: Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.float'
```

If the only thing you want from the `time` module is the `time` function, then you can import that function specifically so that in the scope of your code `time` refers to the function and not the entire module:

```
from time import time

reveal_type(time)       # note: Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.float'
reveal_type(time.time)  # error: "Callable[[], float]" has no attribute "time"
```

So now that we've imported the `time` function directly into our scope, `time()` is correct(because `time` is a function) and `time.time()` is not (because the `time` function does not have a member called `time`).